# How to test whether the ODE integration has reached equilibrium?

Tags: matlab, ode

I am using Matlab for this project. I have introduced some modifications to the `ode45` solver.
I am using sometimes up to 64 components, all in the [0,1] interval and the components sum up to 1.
At some intervals I halt the integration process in order to run a quick check to see whether further integration is needed and I am looking for some clever way to efficiently figure this one.
I have found four cases and I should be able to detect each of them during a check:

1: The system has settled into an equilibrium and all components are unchanged.

2: Three or more components are wildly fluctuating in a periodic manner.

3: One or two components are changing very rapidly with low amplitude and short frequency.

4: None of the above is true and the integration must be continued.

To give an idea: I have found it to be a good practice to use the last ~5k states generated by the `ode45` solver to a function for this purpose.

In short: how does one detect equilibrium or a nonchanging periodic pattern during ODE integration?

Answer (score 1):

Steady-state only occurs when the time derivatives your model function computes are all 0. A periodic solution like you described corresponds rather to a limit cycle, i.e. oscillations around an unstable equilibrium. I don't know if there are methods to detect these cycles. I might update my answers to give more info on that.  Maybe an idea would be to see if the last part of the signal correlates with itself (with a delay corresponding to the cycle period).

Note that if you are only interested in the steady state, an implicit method like ode15s may be more efficient, as it can "dissipate" all the transient fluctuations and use much larger time steps than explicit methods, which must resolve the transient accurately to avoid exploding. However, they may also dissipate small-amplitude limit cycles. A pragmatic solution is then to slightly perturb the steady-state values and see if an explicit integration converges towards the unperturbed steady-state.

Something I often do is to look at the norm of the difference between the solution at each step and the solution at the last step. If this difference is small for a sufficiently high number of steps, then steady-state is reached. You can also observe how the norm $||frac{dy}{dt}||$ converges to zero.

This question is actually better suited for the computational science forum I think.

Comment: +1 to all points. Parallel to or instead of the correlation analysis one could also check if the Fourier transform has clearly defined peaks. (Use windowing to avoid the artifacts of the wrap-around jump.)